# ios swipe gesture not being recognized on subview with gesture on parent view

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have a tableview that holds a number of cells with an image centered in each cell. I set a right swipe gesture on the tabelview. Each image view overrides the touches* methods. I noticed that if I right swipe outside the images, the parent view responds. If I swipe over the image views in the cells, the parent does not respond.

Does the swipe gesture get blocked by the touches* override in the child image subviews?

Answer (score -1):

You may add `UIswipeguesture` to your image subview. So you don't need to override any touch function

```
Uiswipeguesture gues=uiswipeguestu
Imageview addguesture: gues;
```

Comment: I have two questions: 1) Do the touch functions *override the gestures? and 2) Why doesn't the swipe gesture on the parent view apply to the children which are technically subviews?

Comment: 1) I think touch and guesturerecognizer are different implements. If you use touch function, did you call super to chain the responsibility? It's complicated in many situations. 2)swipe guesture is not inherenent by subviews when wrong touch function may override their chance.it's simpler to just use guesture recognizor than mixing them together.